# Twig date difference

Tags: datetime, twig, datediff

I've got an entity with a starting date and an ending date.

Is it possible to get the difference in time between them by using twig?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Since PHP 5.3 There is another option without to write an extension.

This example show how to calc the plural day/days

```
{# endDate and startDate are strings or DateTime objects #}
{% set difference = date(endDate).diff(date(startDate)) %}
{% set leftDays = difference.days %}
{% if leftDays == 1 %}
  1 day
{% else %}
  {{ leftDays }} days
{% endif %}
```

Explanation:

PHP 5.3 `DateTime` object has [`diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method which return a [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object with the result difference between `endDate` and `beginDate`
Twig

Twig [`date`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/date.html) function always return a `DateTime` object so we can call `diff` method

Finally we can access to the properties of the `DateInterval` object or format it with the Twig `date` filter.

Note: There is no need of wrap `endDate` or `startDate` with the `date` function if the variable is already a `DateTime` object.

Note2: `DateTime` is used here as a synonym of `DateTimeInterface`.

Comment: This does work like a dream, however if the difference between the dates is going to be more than a month, use .days instead of .d, .d only returns the days portion, i.e. if the difference is 1 month, 1 day, .d would be 1, but .days would be 32 (assuming a 31 day month).

`{% set leftDays = difference.days %}`

Comment: To get birthdate {{ date().diff(date(item.birth)).y }}

Comment: But either position of both start date and end date will result in one day. How do you determine if it is one day left (+1), or one day over (-1)???

Comment: Awesome dude. You're a twig guru

Comment: @Pathros in the same boat, did you ever come up with a solution?

Comment: difference.invert tells you if it's negative or not
https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Answer (score 13):

There's no built-in function to do that, but you can easily do it yourself, [extending twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html) is easy!

The quick'n'easy way is to do it with twig's simple function class:

```php
$function = new Twig_SimpleFunction('date_difference', function ($start, $end) {
    // ... calculate difference and return it
});

// assuming $twig is an instance of Twig_Environment
$twig->addFunction($function);
```

The reusable way is to create a twig extension (documented on the same link). That's still easy.

Answer (score 4):

Also note there is an existing [Date extension](https://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/date.html) from Sensio Labs that offer a time_diff filter.

Then you can use it like this:`{{ entity.ending_date|time_diff(entity.starting_date) }}`

Please note that this plugin is abandonned and not supported with Twig 3 : https://packagist.org/packages/twig/extensions

Comment: Avoid write or use an extension if an standard option exist, keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 3):

For Symfony 5, I recommand using the [KnpTimeBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpTimeBundle)

it provides the twig function `|ago`

To install : `composer require knplabs/knp-time-bundle`

Comment: Avoid write or use an extension if an standard option exist, keep it as simple as possible.