# get a time difference between two dates

Tags: php, date, symfony, compare, twig

I would like compare the two dates to get a time (Days, Hours, minutes and seconds) difference in TWIG

```
{% set todayDate = ( "now"| date("Y-m-d H:i:s") ) %}  //2013-04-17 08:45:28 
{% set endDate =  (enddate|date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) %}    //2013-04-18 23:59:59
```

How to get hours difference?

Comment: Logic should be kept out of your template. Compare the dates in PHP and assign the difference to a variable that you pass to your template.

Comment: If you are using `set` in a twig template you can be pretty sure, that you should do this in your controller rather than in the template.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twig date difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657687/twig-date-difference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got it..
 compare the two dates to get a time (Days, Hours and  minutes)
 in controller :

(doctrine query)

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), a.enddate) AS endday,    
(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), a.enddate) - TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),a.enddate)*24) AS endhour,
(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), a.enddate) - TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), a.enddate)*60) AS endmin,
```

Created a function for TIMESTAMPDIFF 
https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/DoctrineExtensions/Query/Mysql/TimestampDiff.php

and include a snippet

app->config->config.yml 
doctrine:
    dbal:
        ........

```
orm:
    entity_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true
            dql:
                datetime_functions:
                    timestampdiff: Acme\BUNDLE\FOLDER\TimestampDiff
```

Thanks to all ..

Answer (score 0):

Since you pass the enddate to your template, you should do this in your controller and pass the result to your template.

Here is the php code you could use:

```
$now = new DateTime('now');
$dateToCompare = new DateTime('your date');

$difference = $now->format('U') - $dateToCompare->format('U');
// or if your date to compare is in the future :
// $difference = $dateToCompare->format('U') - $now->format('U');
$time_diff = gmdate('H',$difference);

echo $time_diff;
```