# PHP and MYSQL date expiry near

Tags: php, mysql, date

What I wish to do is when the user logs in I want to notify them that the product is going to expire

Any ideas of what queries I need to use for this and how I can do this please?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.ProductName, s.Quantity, s.Price, s.DateExpiry FROM seller s, Product p
WHERE p.PID = s.PID AND DateExpiry < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND Custid = $_SESSION['user']
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do should be adding some "time math" to your condition:

```
WHERE p.PID = s.PID AND DateExpiry < ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND Custid = $_SESSION['user']
```

This will use the time from now in 3 days rather than the current time to do the comparison.

Of course, you can change the interval at any time, e.g. using `INTERVAL 1 DAY` to only add 1 day.

Valid Units can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).

As an alternative, you can just write a simple addition, if you're using a not too old server version:

```
WHERE p.PID = s.PID AND DateExpiry < NOW() + INTERVAL 3 DAY AND Custid = $_SESSION['user']
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change the query one bit, but you have to do some calculating with the data you have, now i dont know what formate you dateexpiry is, but it could look something like this.

**Code:**

```
$now = new DateTime('now');
$dateToCompare = new DateTime('2013-04-11');//here is where you put your dateexpire variable

$difference = $now->format('U') - $dateToCompare->format('U');
// or if your date to compare is in the future :
// $difference = $dateToCompare->format('U') - $now->format('U');
$time_diff = gmdate('d',$difference);

echo $time_diff;
if($time_diff == 3):
echo "there is 3 days left";
elseif($time_diff < 3):
echo "less then 3 day there will be 10% reduction";
endif;
```

**Code taken from :** [get a time difference between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053799/get-a-time-difference-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 0):

**Check this**

```
SELECT p.ProductName, s.Quantity, s.Price, s.DateExpiry FROM seller s, Product p
WHERE p.PID = s.PID AND Custid = $_SESSION['user'] AND
(DateExpiry BETWEEN curdate() and curdate() + interval 3 day) ORDER BY DateExpiry
```