# Using datediff in twig to determine whether a date is before or after a given date

Tags: symfony, date, twig

I need to be able to calculate a difference between a due date for an invoice and the current date, so I can flag appropriate warning messages regarding the urgency of payment, in a Twig file in Symfony.

I implemented the solution given here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27205095/5194337

and although it works, it cannot tell if it is before the due date or after, it only calculates the difference in days. So, if the invoice is two days overdue, it returns 2 which it will also return if it's due IN two days which doesn't really help.

Here is my code:

```
{% if invoice['invoice'].datePaid != null %}
    {{ invoice['invoice'].datePaid|date('d/m/Y') }}
{% else %}
    {% set difference = date(invoice['invoice'].dateDue).diff(date('now')) %}
    {% set leftDays = difference.days %}
    {% if date(invoice.['invoice'].dateDue) < date|('now') %}
        <span class="overdue">Overdue</span>
    {% elseif leftDays < 3 and leftDays > 0 %}
        <span class="unpaid">Due in {{ leftDays }} day(s)</span>
    {% else %}
        <span class="unpaid">Unpaid</span>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

As you can see I used `{% if date(invoice.['invoice'].dateDue) < date|('now') %}` to try and see if the due date was in the past but I get the following error:

> Expected name or number.

And that happens however I try to format the dates. How can I use this calculation accurately, as I am not sure what the error even means?

Comment: are you sure you want to do it in twig template? to me that sounds like some logic which is better off in services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error. This:

```
invoice.['invoice'].datePaid
```

has an extra dot. It should be:

```
invoice['invoice'].datePaid
{# or #}
invoice.invoice.datePaid
```

The error means that because you can access array/object values with the dot notation, Twig expects that a period is followed by a name (array key; e.g. `myArray.someKey`) or a number (array index; e.g. `myArray.2`). But now you have a `[` which is not a valid character when using the dot notation.

(Besides, your Twig code is so complex that this kind of thing might be better done e.g. in your controller, like @LBA already suggested.)

Answer (score 0):

[Twig date function](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/date.html) returns current date, if no argument is supplied, so you can use:

```
{% if date(invoice['invoice'].dateDue) < date() %}
```

The pipe operator is used to [display and format a date](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/date.html):

```
{{ "now"|date("m/d/Y") }}
```

Comment: This will also raise the error "Expected name or number." See my answer.

Comment: @martias you're right, there was a syntax error as well