# How to create a function in twig to calculate the age of a person using Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have this PHP code that works but I would like to be able to use the same but within `twig` in `symfony`.

```
<?php
    $cumpleanos = new DateTime("1982-06-03");
    $hoy = new DateTime();
    $annos = $hoy->diff($cumpleanos);
    echo $annos->y;
```

Comment: Assuming you do not have an entity to attach this behaviour to - it's probably best practice to do this sort of calculation in your controller, and send the computed value to Twig.

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/27205095/9750031

Comment: I think they are extensions of twig but they solve different problems

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To make this code guide me in this post: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/73288/6524

The only variant in the file `EdadUsuarioExtension.php`

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Twig;

//Extension muestra la edad del usuario
class EdadUsuarioExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('edad_usuario', array($this, 'edad_usuario')),
        );   
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'edad_usuario_extension';
    }

    public function edad_usuario($fecha)
    {
        $cumpleanos = new \DateTime($fecha);
        $hoy = new \DateTime();
        $edad = $hoy->diff($cumpleanos);
    
        return $edad->y;
    }
}
```