# How to display with TWIG if the user is online or offline?

Tags: if-statement, drupal, twig, drupal-8

On my Drupal 8 site, I want to put a code in the user's template to display his status (online, absent or offline).

I want to do this only with TWIG, without creating a custom module.

In the conditions, how then to calculate the last access of the user and the current time ?

https://docs.w3cub.com/drupal~8/core-lib-drupal-core-session-usersession.php/function/usersession-getlastaccessedtime/8.1.x/

Here is what I want to put in condition :

- If the user has accessed the site for less than 15 minutes, he is online.
- Otherwise, if the user has accessed the site for more than 15 minutes and less than 30 minutes, he is absent.
- Otherwise it is offline.

user--full.html.twig :

```
  {% if ??? %}
    <div class="mt-2 text-center font-weight-bold font-italic text-success">
      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-lg"></i> Online
    </div>
  {% elseif ??? %}
    <div class="mt-2 text-center font-weight-bold font-italic text-warning">
      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-lg"></i> Absent
    </div>
  {% else %}
    <div class="mt-2 text-center font-weight-bold font-italic text-danger">
      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-lg"></i> Offline
    </div>
  {% endif %}
```

**UPDATE 1**

The following code displays the "timestamp" of the last access :

```
{{ user.access.value }}
```

The following code displays the current "timestamp" :

```
{{ 'now'|date('U') }}
```

How to calculate and display the correct status ?

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#math

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

The answer works, here is the result of the operation :

```
{{ date().timestamp }}
{{ user.access.value }}
{{ (date().timestamp - user.access.value) }}
```

[image]

But there is a problem, if I reload the page, the number never changes. To update it I must empty the cache.

```
  {% if (date().timestamp - user.access.value) < 900 %}
    <div class="mt-2 text-center font-weight-bold font-italic text-success">
      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-lg"></i> Online
    </div>
  {% elseif (date().timestamp - user.access.value) < 1800 %}
    <div class="mt-2 text-center font-weight-bold font-italic text-warning">
      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-lg"></i> Absent
    </div>
  {% else %}
    <div class="mt-2 text-center font-weight-bold font-italic text-danger">
      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-lg"></i> Offline
    </div>
  {% endif %}
```

**UPDATE 3**

Currently I am using a view with EVA and the view cache disabled.

I want to reproduce the same behavior directly in TWIG. The response code works, but I want to disable the cache for the user status element (online, absent, offline).

[image]

[image]

[image]

I added the code below in the `bootstrap_subtheme_front_office_old.theme` file of my sub-theme.

It is not correct, how to target only the status code ?

```
/**
 * User online status.
 */
function bootstrap_subtheme_front_office_old_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['plugin_id'] == 'block_id') {
    $variables['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Twig date difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657687/twig-date-difference)

Comment: These pages are cached. You will probably need to set the cache type in a preprocess function (Cache max-age: 0 to disable cache on these pages maybe). If it was me, I would also do the logic for the user status in the preprocess function too and then send the variable to the template.

Comment: @2pha https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2016-04-28/how-to-display-current-timestamp-in-a-template Can we deactivate the cache just for the date? I don't know how to do a preprocessing, I would like to avoid making a personalized module

Comment: See [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185215/how-do-i-disable-twig-and-block-cache-for-a-specific-module)

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: The preprocess code you added to the question works on blocks, but judging from the twig file name `user--full.html.twig`, you are working with the whole page, so the preprocess block won't work. You probably want to use [template_preprocess_page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/8.8.x)

Comment: @2pha Thank you, is it possible to click in ID or a DIV or a class for the user status element on my page? Or maybe a display, I have several displays in "manage the display" of the user.

Comment: I don't understand the above comment. In a preprocess, you are working with PHP, not rendered HTML. I think you can set the whole page not to cache by using a preprocess_page and setting `$variables['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;`

Comment: I found [this question on drupal answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/273973/show-if-a-user-is-online-idle-or-offline-on-their-account-page/273986) that seems to be quite similar. One of the people that answered created a module [HERE](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_online_status) which gets around the caching issue by using javascript to inject the status. Though, the module could have been simplified by just using a custom block that loads via bigpipe It may be helpful though.

Comment: @2pha I have already tested this module and the performance of the site after its installation is catastrophic. In my previous comment, I asked if it is possible to deactivate the hide for "manage display" displays. Or for a DIV.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/user_status_online and https://www.drupal.org/project/user_online_status There are 2 modules, but it does not work could create a big performance problem. I don't understand why drupal does not integrate this essential functionality on modern sites. How do developers develop to display this ? There is nothing in contrib module for this basic functionality

Comment: If I understood correctly, it is not possible to exclude part of the TWIG code from the cache?

Answer (score 1):

`user.access.value` holds a timestamp (in seconds), so you can try the following :

```
  {% set elapsed = date().timestamp - user.access.value %}}      

  {% if elapsed < 15*60 %}
    <div class="mt-2 text-center font-weight-bold font-italic text-success">
      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-lg"></i> Online
    </div>
  {% elseif elapsed < 30*60 %}
    <div class="mt-2 text-center font-weight-bold font-italic text-warning">
      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-lg"></i> Absent
    </div>
  {% else %}
    <div class="mt-2 text-center font-weight-bold font-italic text-danger">
      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-lg"></i> Offline
    </div>
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you it's much better. I tested, but the user never goes offline.

Comment: Are you sure you get the correct `user` variable ? The code works, if 30 minutes elapsed since the last user access, it will go in the corresponding condition block.

Comment: It doesn't work for offline. The two variables displays the values as in the screenshot

Comment: Well, it works for me. I guess your template got the wrong user variable here, ie. `user` could just be the curent user, not *those* (ie. `user` in an iteration of `users`) corresponding to *each* user profile that may populate your template.

Comment: I have updated my question ** UPDATE 2 ** the problem is the cache of the current date.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2016-04-28/how-to-display-current-timestamp-in-a-template Same question but no answer

Comment: It works, but the problem is the cache. Did you test?

Comment: No, but I would recommend using a preprocess function where you can build the status part given the last user access.

Comment: Do you need to do this in a custom module for the ".theme" file ?