# Datediff on View global:custom-text

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-views

I have a view that has "Published date" as a hidden field. I want to show a

tag when the difference between current date and published date is <=3 then show a

tag with some content. So I tried the below code in a **global:custom-text field**:

```
 {% if diff(date({{ now|date("m/d/Y") }}),date({{ published_at|date("m/d/Y") }})) <=3) %}
<div class="classa">
<div class="classb">
  {{ field_file }}{{ field_link }} {{ field_other }} <p>New!</p>
</div>
{% else %}
<div class="classb">
  {{ field_file }}{{ field_link }} {{ field_other }} <p>Old!</p>
</div>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

This code is not working. Basically "difference" is not working. Any help to fix this issue? Thanks

Comment: `{{ ... }}` is used to output variables, you shouldn't use them inside twig statement. Also why are you mixing the `date` function and filter?

Comment: I am trying to find the difference between the published date and current date. Can you pls guide on how to fix this pls?

Comment: `{% if diff(date("NOW"), date(published_at)) <= 3) %}`

Comment: This condition is not working.  I get "Twig\Error\SyntaxError: Unknown "diff" function in "__string_template" error :(

Comment: Well `diff` isn't a default twig function AFAIK - See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657687/twig-date-difference) or you could do `date("NOW").diff(date(published_at))` but that would return a `DateInterval` object

Comment: I want to implement this through the UI for ease. is there any other way to implement this functionality via view UI itself?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use this inside the template and don't want to extend `twig` then u can make use of [`DateTime.diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) which returns a [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object

```
{% if date("NOW").diff(date(published_at)).d <= 3 %}
    Output
{% endif %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/8k1vgi)

Comment: The above example is not working when used on the custom-text field. I see "Calling "diff" method on a "DateTime" object is not allowed in "__string_template" error